# No System Model and System Manufacturer name?

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-info

In System Information these fields seems to be missing. why this information is not provided?

[image]

System Model is System Product Name which is really weird, as well as System Manufacture. Is there something i should worry about?

There was a security fix by intel and in [ASUS support information](https://www.asus.com/News/q5R9EixxfAqo1anZ) i was supposed to check for the model name, instead i found these weird names.

Comment: " why this information is not provided?" - Because you do not have an OEM hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In System Information these fields seems to be missing. why this information is not provided?

You have not filled out the information.  Those fields are normally filled out by an OEM.  You have a Maximus VIII Hero Alpha motherboard.  The values you are seeing are the default values.

> There was a security fix by Intel and in ASUS support information I was supposed to check for the model name, instead, I found these weird names.

You could also download the [MEUpdateTool](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/Z170-A/MEUpdateTool_UI_20171103_TP.zip?_ga=2.152290873.1449187323.1554420426-404499464.1535602866) from ASUS.

While I recommend you use the current ME firmware, [11.7.0.1040](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/03CHIPSET/Consumer_11.7.0.1040.zip?_ga=2.73975314.1449187323.1554420426-404499464.1535602866) isn't actually vulnerable to any of the Intel ME exploits.

The following CVE IDs are covered in this security advisory:

> Intel® Manageability Engine Firmware
>   11.0.x.x/11.5.x.x/11.6.x.x/11.7.x.x/11.10.x.x/11.20.x.x

Source: [Intel Q3’17 ME 6.x/7.x/8.x/9.x/10.x/11.x, SPS 4.0, and TXE 3.0 Security Review Cumulative Update](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/security-center/advisory/intel-sa-00086.html)

Since you don't have ASUS OEM hardware, you need to patch the Intel software yourself, by downloading the update directly from Intel's website. You should first, identify if your system is actually vulnerable, by using the [Intel-SA-00086 Detection Tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27150?v=t).  If it is vulnerable then download the current [Intel Management Engine](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28679/Intel-Management-Engine-Driver-for-Windows-8-1-and-Windows-10) driver directly from Intel.

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded the tool and it said my system is not vulnerable. good to know about OEM, ill look more into that.

Comment: @Stevoisiak - What does that have to do with the author's question?  If you have your own question, you should ask a question, I will not be answering any question asked in a comment to this answer.  **I will report those comments as not being necessary though.**